# How to get a list of all ForeignKey's in django

Tags: python, django, web, uploader

I'm trying to create a simple upload center with accounting .
I have a `User` and a `File` `model` like this :

```
class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    short_discripton = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=False)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField("Uploaded Date", auto_now_add=True)
    def upload_date(self):
        return timezone.datetime.now()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class User(models.Model):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    user_path = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)

    creation_date = models.DateTimeField("Register Date", auto_now_add=True)
    files = models.ForeignKey(File, null=True, blank=True)   
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.userna
```

me

But when i try to retrieve the files using :

```
all_user_files = File.objects.get(pk=user.id)
```

It only returns one of the files though there is more files in the database(checking admin panel).

And the other way when i use :

```
user_all_files = user.files_set.all()
```

It will raise the error :

```
'User' object has no attribute 'files_set'
```

I'm really confused with that.Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need delete `files = models.ForeignKey(File, null=True, blank=True)`

And add to File (model) `user= models.ForeignKey(User)`

example here [docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_one](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_one)

Comment: why is that ? i want the user to have his/her own files .

Comment: Of course, example here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/